# Displaying PDF file .net asp C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I want to display a PDF file and it working but when i'm clicking the saveing button it ask me to save a aspx page and not PDF file?
this is my code:

```
string path = CanvasWritingStepImages._pdfName;
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
         Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(path);

          if (buffer != null)
          {
              //content-disposition
              Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
              Response.AddHeader("content-length", "attachment ;filename=Formulike.PDF");
             Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);


          }
          else
          {
              logger.Error("Buffer was Null!");
          }
```

how i can make it a PDF file when i'm saving it?
may be to open in new tab? if so,
how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this line

```
Response.AddHeader("content-length", "attachment; filename=Formulike.PDF");
```

With this

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Formulike.pdf");
```

You can also use

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=Formulike.pdf");
```

Changing from `attachment` to `inline` will cause the pdf to be displayed in the browser window rather than prompt with a save/open dialog

Comment: is there a way to do it both? display and download?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @kelix i found a way to make it both download PDF and show PDF

```
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=Formulike.pdf");
              Response.AddHeader("content-length", "attachment ;filename=Formulike.PDF");
```

the "inline" is important.